# Cannot resolve constructor 'BottomSheetDialog()'

Tags: android, android-studio, bottom-sheet

I followed a tutorial but the codes did not work well. On the tutorial, he only types the `BottomSheetDialog();` and doesn't have requirements inside the parenthesis but on my activity, it requires to put something there and I don't know it.

```
private GoogleMap mMap;
ArrayList<LatLng> MarkerPoints;
GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
Location mLastLocation;
Marker mCurrLocationMarker;
LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
double mLatitude;
double mLongitude;
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
private Button btnShow;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

    // Initialize Firebase Auth

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        checkLocationPermission();
    }
    // Initializing
    MarkerPoints = new ArrayList<>();

    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    btnShow = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bottomsheet);
    btnShow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            BottomSheetDialog bottomSheetDialog = new BottomSheetDialog();
            bottomSheetDialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(),bottomSheetDialog.getTag());
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the `BottomSheetDialog` code, only one these constructors are supported:

```
public BottomSheetDialog(@NonNull Context context) {
    ...
}

public BottomSheetDialog(@NonNull Context context, @StyleRes int theme) {
    ...
}
```

So you are missing a `context` parameter:

```
BottomSheetDialog bottomSheetDialog = new BottomSheetDialog(context);
```

Comment: sir I have compile the design since Im using android studio 2.3.3

Comment: sir I have that but on my setupDialog like this                                  
    @Override  
    public void setupDialog(Dialog dialog, int style) {    
        super.setupDialog(dialog p, style);

        View contentView = View.inflate(getContext(), R.layout.durationscreen, null);  
        dialog.setContentView(contentView);

Comment: @MayaRoales you need to add it also when you create a new `BottomSheetDialog`

Comment: @MayaRoales did it solve your issue? If so, mark the answer as the correct so it can help others ;)